# Automatic registration of derived classes with C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

As other users I'm trying to achieve something impossible or very complicated. I read many questions, like "iterating all derived classes", but as I see, it's impossible. But I want to ask is possible to make registration of derived classes automatically. Maybe with using some templates. Or for example use template function with special name (for example `template<typename T> void register(SomeFabric* f, T* t = new T())`) and iterate through all 'registed' types (if it's possible, ofc). Or use another special function (for example `void register(SomeFabric* f, Base* base)`) and iterate through all available classes and if this special function can be called with this arguments and if iteratable class can be instantiated - call it.
If it's totaly impossible: what's the easiest (lowest number of developer actions) way to register class?

Comment: You seem to want a self registering abstract factory. Something like described here: http://www.dorodnic.com/blog/2014/03/29/abstract-factory/

Comment: @Baldrick Ye, this is someting I tought about. Thankyou for link. It's very useful. If noone will offer something more usefull I guess I'll ask you to write it like answer.

Comment: You are talking about a solution to some problem.  The solution is something to do with "iterating over all derived classes" or "registering derived classes". First, what that means is *not clear* (do you mean instances?  Classes?  What about said classes do you want to iterate over or have in the registry?), and working out what features you want is impossible as you don't mention the underlying problem that this "solution" is trying to solve. Please clarify with the underlying problem.  Be explicit what you mean by iterate over derived classes, and give concrete examples of program behavior.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution is to keep list of derived classes in **base class static field**:

```
static vector<*BaseClass> children;
```

Then **register** new instances in the BaseClass constructor:

```
children.push_back(this)
```

And **remove** from registry in the base class destructor.

Don't forget to **call parent constructor** from derived class:

```
Derived(int a, int b) : BaseClass() {...}
```

Notice that while this solution will work, it is **poor from architectural point** of view. It introduce global state and all problems connected with it.

Comment: What is `*MyClass`?

Comment: renamed it to BaseClass.

Comment: What is `*BaseClass`?  Those tokens make no sense.  Changing the identifier does not improve it.